# Why LED light delay is 5 second in arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, led

My code :

```
int pin = 8;
int pout = 12;
int result=0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(pout, OUTPUT);  
}

void loop() {

  result = digitalRead(pin);

  if(result == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(pout, HIGH); 
    delay(1000);
  }
  if(result == 0)
  { 
    digitalWrite(pout, LOW); 
  }

}
```

I have set delay 1 sec but whenever i put high voltage on pin 8 The LED glow for 5 second. why?

How to set delay to none ? means whenever the pin 8 is HIGH the LED will glow else off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem (likely) isn't in your code. You need to include a pull-down resistor in your electronics, so that when you remove the "high voltage" the residual charge stored in the pin due to its capacitance can be drained. Alternatively you can use the internal pull-up resistors, but then you'd need to invert the logic of the pin (high becomes low and vice versa) and instead of connecting "high voltage" you'd need to connect ground to activate the LED.

Comment: **1.** changed `result=1 digitalWrite(pout, LOW)`and result=0 `digitalWrite(pout, HIGH)` still have the same issue LED glow for 3,4 second **2.** also use this `if(result=1) digitalWrite(pout, HIGH); delay(100);digitalWrite(pout, LOW);` still no luck LED goes on and off for 3,4 sec. **3.** I have put 6k ohms resistor  between LED still No luck. :(

Comment: You need to put the resistor between pin 8 and ground, not on the LED.

Comment: ohh, awesome :) works now thanks. added 2.2k ohms worked and 680 Ohms is also working. Could you please let me know how to choose resistors?

Comment: The precise value doesn't matter. A relatively high value like 10k is customary. The higher the resistor, the less current is wasted when the switch is on, but the slower the residual charge will drain.